# How to allow Ejabberd external XMPP component to send presence packets on behalf of a user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I wrote an external component for Ejabberd, but when trying to send presence stanzas on behalf of a user i get a 400 error.

The component's name is bot.domain.com and the host name in Ejabberd is domain.com and I have set the "check_from" flag to false for my component.

Below is an example of a presence stanza I am trying to send from the component on behalf of a user:

```
<presence from="user@domain.com">
    <status>Test status</status>
    <show>dnd</show>
</presence>
```

And this is the error message that is returned by Ejabberd:

```
<presence type="error" to="user@domain.com">
    <status>Test status</status>
    <show>dnd</show>
    <error code="400" type="modify">
         <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
    </error>
</presence>
```

If I add to="user2@domain.com" in the package I'm sending, the destination user actually receives the package.

If I add to="domain.com", I don't get the 400 error anymore, but the presence is not broadcast to anyone in the user's roster.

**The actual problem seems to be that Ejabberd is not broadcasting the presence packet to everyone in the user's roster.**

Any ideas what I might be missing or why I get the 400 error when not specifying the "to" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot broadcast roster presence on behalf of a user from a component. Component service does not load the user roster. Only the `ejabberd_c2s` is taking care of loading roster to broadcast presence. It also takes care of checking privacy list and many important features of XMPP.

As a side note, I do not know what you expect to do with that approach, but you can split presence from user session in XMPP. A user is online first because he has a session open on XMPP and only secondarily because he sent a presence. By faking presence sending from component for a users, you are not guaranteed that that user will have a session opened. In that case, the overall behaviour will certainly not the one you expect.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, the purpose was to use a component only for updating the user's status message when they are browsing a specific section of our website. As you specified above, there is no way to do this with a standard Ejabberd installation, so the only way was to modify the ejabberd_service module to broadcast presence packets sent by our component on behalf of users.